# How to enable/disable a checkbox

Tags: python, python-2.7, checkbox, tkinter, state

I'm having some difficulties with this code.

I just want to make some widgets active after some process. For now I can get the buttons enabled, but not the checkboxes, and i can't find out what i'm doing wrong.

I made this simple code to illustrate the problem:

```
import Tkinter as tk

root=tk.Tk()

class Application (tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_windgets()

    def DoNothing(self):
        print ""

    def Compute(self):
        self.sampleButton['state']='normal'
        self.CB1['state']='normal'

    def create_windgets (self):        

        self.sampleButton=tk.Button(self, text="Sample",state='disable' , command=self.DoNothing)
        self.sampleButton.grid()

        self.EDButton=tk.Button(self, text="Enable", command=self.Compute)
        self.EDButton.grid()

        self.o1=tk.BooleanVar()
        self.CB1=tk.Checkbutton(self,text="submit",state='disable' , variable =self.o1).grid()

app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

It is returnig:
self.CB1['state']='normal'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grid` method does return `None`; You need to separate the following line:

```
self.CB1=tk.Checkbutton(self,text="submit",state='disable' , variable=self.o1).grid()
```

into two statement:

```
self.CB1 = tk.Checkbutton(self,text="submit",state='disable' , variable=self.o1)
self.CB1.grid()
```